# How do I keep the objects form created by a skeleton when deleting the skeleton

Tags: mesh, objects, armature

I have an object which is in a good position but when I delete the skeleton the object goes back to its original form.  I am not trying to animate the object or anything I just want if in the current form.  Thanks!

Comment: Apply the armature modifier? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Hehe does that solve your problem ?